# Unable to access "create content" "blocks" or "my account" on new drupal installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm switching one of my clients websites over to Drupal and when I try to navigate to Create Content, Site Building -> Blocks, or My Account it redirects me to my client's existing homepage with a path that seems like it should work (ex. domain.com/?q=node/add).

I've searched the stack and googled about the problem and haven't found any solutions.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: interestingly, when I enabled "Clean URLs" (which changes the path to admin/build/block) it brings me to the homepage without my css sheet being applied.

Edit x2: Solved my own question. I'll be accepting my own answer after the time limit, and don't need any more help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, Kirk! Your theme (page.tpl.php) doesn't include `<?php echo $content; ?>` which is one of those really basic foundation things in drupal.